# MFP Analytics not getting captured

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibm-mobile-services

We are using MFP 8 which is in bluemix. We tried logging some custom logs to MFP analytics, but it is not getting captured. This is a Cordova app. And there are no error logs also while sending logs to analytics server. As I am new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using Mobile Foundation service on Bluemix. If so, did you create the Analytics based container via the service? Also, is it just the custom logs that are not being seen in the analytics console or all the data are missing? Can you please give more details

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the App has connected successfully to MFP server before sending the custom data

Code should look like

```
WL.Analytics.log({"myKey" : "myValue"}); 
WL.Analytics.send();
```

View using **Analytics console > Apps > Client Log Search** - Click search button

Reference: [Using Analytics API in Client Applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/analytics-api/)

Comment: Thanks @Kumar for your response..... But we are already using it.... Do we need to do any configuration in config file? Or any specific sequence need to be follow?

Comment: If you are using mfp-devkit it is well and good by default analytics is configured. If you are using analytics installed separately you need to configure it manually

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/analytics/configuration/

Comment: JNDI Properties to be configured on MFP Server : mfp.analytics.console.url, mfp.analytics.url, analyticsconsole/mfp.analytics.url, mfp.analytics.username, mfp.analytics.password

Comment: we are using mfp-devkit only.....in app.js file using below code to activate logging  >>>> WL.Logger.config({capture: true});  WL.Logger.config({autoSendLogs: true}); WL.Logger.config({ level: 'DEBUG' }); WL.Logger.config({ level: 'INFO' });   and in respective controller to capture and send event  logger.debug('User clicked on '+obj.title);
    logger.info('User clicked on '+obj.title);WL.Analytics.log({"myKey" : "myValue"}); 
WL.Analytics.send();

Comment: Were you able to see the App related data on Analytics or just custom logging? This is to make sure the analytics is healthy. 

I missed to see that you are using Analytics on Bluemix. Please make sure the MFP server's  data is flowing to analytics.